# How to sort the keys with alphanumeric in TreeMap

Tags: java, sorting, key, treemap

I have following `TreeMap`:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>();            

result.put("Tier 1",  "My First String", "My First String ABC");
result.put("Tier 2",  "My First String", "My First String DEF");
result.put("Tier 3",  "My First String", "My First String DDD");
result.put("Tier 10", "My Last String", "My First String TTT");
```

Printed out result is not in order at "**Tier 10**" `String`:

```
Tier 1,  My First String, My First String ABC
Tier 10, My First String, My First String TTT
Tier 2,  My First String, My First String DEF
Tier 3,  My First String, My First String DDD
```

I would like it to be in logical order:

```
Tier 1,  My First String, My First String ABC
Tier 2,  My First String, My First String DEF
Tier 3,  My First String, My First String DDD
Tier 10, My First String, My First String TTT
```

I tried to use `Comparator` as follows:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>(
    new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
      }
    });
```

but that didn't help.

Comment: Define Comparator that does your desired comparision and use it.

Comment: I did define a Comparator but it didn't work

Comment: You probably want to use a natural-order sort.  The compareTo() method will do a alphabetic sort.

Comment: Have you considered a richer type for the key than just a `String`? Perhaps something like a simple object that has a `String` named "label" and an `Integer` named "index"? (But don't forget to implement `equals` and `hashCode`!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda expressions to easily define a `Comparator`:

```
TreeMap<String, String> result = new TreeMap<String, String>((String s1, String s2) -> {
    Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s1);
    Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s2);
    m1.find();
    m2.find();
    return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(m1.group()), Integer.parseInt(m2.group()));
});

result.put("Tier 3",  "My First String");
result.put("Tier 10", "My Last String");
result.put("Tier 1",  "My First String");
result.put("Tier 2",  "My First String");

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

> {Tier 1=My First String, Tier 2=My First String, Tier 3=My First String, Tier 10=My Last String}

Comment: My TreeMap contains more than just "Tier XXX".  So many other Strings with some text and numeric values.  For example, Bridge 1, Bridge 20, Cost 1 to Cost 100.

Comment: Maljam, My TreeMap is Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>()

Comment: Maljam, What is the -->?  I am new to Java

Comment: that's a recent addition to Java called lambda expressions that allows you to give methods as parameters in another method/constructor. It has the same idea as implementing `Comparator` and defining the `compare()` method, it just saves code and improves readability. You can read about it: [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: I am getting "The method compare(int, int) is undefined for the type Integer"

Comment: Not sure, it works when I test it, but you can replace with `Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))`

Comment: Thanks for your time Maljam but it is not working for me.  I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I now have and works great: (Answered my own question here)

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, String>>(
    new Comparator<String>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        Integer i1 = null;
        Integer i2 = null;
        int retVal = 99;

        if (containsDigit(s1) && containsDigit(s2) && (extractString(s1).equals(extractString(s2)))) {
          i1 = new Integer(extractNumber(s1));
          i2 = new Integer(extractNumber(s2));

          if (i1 != null && i2 != null) {
            retVal = i1.compareTo(i2);
          }
        } else {
          retVal = s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
        return retVal;
      }
    });
```

Other supported methods:

```
private String extractNumber(final String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return emptyString_;
    }
    return str.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}", emptyString_).trim();
   }

private String extractString(final String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
      return emptyString_;
    }
    return str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", emptyString_);
}

private boolean containsDigit(String s) {
    boolean found = false;
    if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
      for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
           found = true;
           break;
        }
      }
    }
     return found;
   }
```